# Polymer web component testing: How to import dummy test data from a local .json file

Tags: javascript, json, polymer, web-component-tester

I'd like to set a variable full of dummy data for use in testing.
In my-element_test.html how can I do this?

In an actual element, I would use iron-ajax with a local file for the url and just use the last-response variable around my code.

Do I need to copy and paste all of the text into my test file like var dummyData = ""?

Answer (score 1):

```
let data = await fetch('/data.json')
    .then(promise => promise);
```

Fetch returns a promise that you need to await on. In order to use await, you must define the test function as async.